# Unit test metodo Verify moq falla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pruebas-unitarias

estoy haciendo una prueba sencilla, sin embargo me muestra un error al ejecutarse ,la prueba es:

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void Test_RegistrarUnNuevoUsuario()
        {
            //Arrange
            var repositorioMock = new Mock<IUsuarioRepositorio>();
            repositorioMock.Setup(x => x.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>()));



             //Assert
            repositorioMock.Verify(m=>m.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>()),Times.Once);


        }
```

De acuerdo con la documentacion solo es necesario la misma firma en el argumento que se declara en setup, pero nada me sigue mostrando el error:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>())
```

Alguna idea?, gracias.

Comment: Ahora veo que dejaste sin respuesta la pregunta. Puede editar y comentar como se resolvio marcando la respuesta que te ayudo a conseguir ese objetivo

Comment: si elimine la respuesta que fue como quedo en mi prueba y  modifique la  solucion que tu diste, @LeandroTuttini, gracias.

Comment: pero no tienes que editar mi respuesta, edita tu pregunta agegando al final como lo resolviste, puede poner un titulo al final de solucion y explicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El exceptio se genera porque estas verificando algo que no se cumple, deberias invocar

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_RegistrarUnNuevoUsuario()
{
    //Arrange
    var repositorioMock = new Mock<IUsuarioRepositorio>();
    repositorioMock.Setup(x => x.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>()));

    //Execute
    var repo = repositorioMock.Object;

    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    repo.CrearUsuario(user);


    //Assert
    repositorioMock.Verify(m=>m.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>()),Times.Once);

}
```

Tienes que ejecutarse en este caso lo hice directo, pero podria ser por la llamada desde otro objeto que lo usa internamente, previa inyecion de la dependencia en el constructor de esa clase

Comment: Cierto, lo llamaba implementando un servicio de registro pero lo borre y me concentre en que la firma fuera igual It.Any, gracias.